# How to create a button to run script commands

Tags: python, scripting

I wrote a script. I want to trigger this script with a button. What are the problems in the script?
Error: Registering operator class: 'instance', invalid bl_idname 'instanceMesh', at position 8

````
import bpy
class instance(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "instance.mesh"
    bl_label = "instanceMesh"
    #bl_description = "Append object to your blend file"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    def execute(self,context):
        cube = bpy.context.object 
        cd = cube.dimensions
        col = bpy.context.collection
        for o in col.objects: 
            d = o.dimensions
            o.data = cube.data
            o.scale = d.x/cd.x, d.y/cd.y, d.z/cd.z
        return{'FINISHED'}
# 1. Create class
class TestPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label="instanceMesh"
    #bl_idname="PT_Test Panel"
    bl_space_type="VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type="UI"
    bl_category="instanceMesh" #SideBar Name
    def draw(self,context):
        layout=self.layout       
        obj = context.object
        col = context.collection
        row=layout.row()    #Create a new row
        row.prop(obj, "name",icon= "LIGHTPROBE_CUBEMAP") 
        row=layout.row()  
        row.prop(col, "name",icon= "LIGHTPROBE_CUBEMAP")  
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("instance.mesh", icon="FILE",text = "run")
        row.scale_y = 2
# 3.Update the Modified Class        
classes = [
    instance,
    TestPanel,
]        
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: So do you want a button that makes the panel pop up or the `instanceMesh()` function to run?

Comment: You need to add an `bpy.types.Operator` derived class that has an `execute` routine that calls `instanceMesh` (or implements it) and then you need to add an `operator` layout function that  refers to the operator class you created.

Comment: In the text editor go to Templates > Python > Operator simple

Comment: I found the answer, thank you everyone

Comment: What is the answer?